# how to include a view in another view in cakephp2

Tags: layout, view, include, cakephp-2.0

I want to place login.ctp (a view for login) into page.ctp, which is the main view for may app and i'm stuck here  please help

Answer (score 0):

You can create login view as an element and render it in the page.ctp.